How to implement the following SDP with python
I'm confused about how one can implement a semi-definite programming routine with python. Apologies if similar questions have already been asked!
What I could like is to optimize over probabilities $p_i$ that sum to 1. Specifically, the problem is to find the minimum of $\sum_i p_i c_i$ given $\sum_i p_i A_i$ is positive semi-definite (and $\sum_i p_i = 1$ with $p_i \ge 0 \forall i$). Here, $c_i$ is a real number, and $A_i$ is a real symmetric matrix (which are by themselves not necessarily positive semi-definite).

Very easy to formulate in CVXPY, which can call a free or non-free SDP solver to solve it.

What SDP solver do you intent to use?
